# Printing Month Name in Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Is there any Inbuilt function in Linq to Print the month Name while working with LINQPAD?

I want to print the month name in the following Scenario

```
var query = from e in Employees
           let month=e.BirthDate.GetValueOrDefault()
           let birthmonth=month.ToString("MMMM")
           select birthmonth;
           query.Dump();
```

When I run this it is throwing NotSupportedException.
how to print the month name in Linq to Sql?

Comment: Please be more specific. The month name of what? In what context? It's impossible to answer your question while it's so vague.

Comment: No, linq does not have a inbuild function to print the month name. You're probably looking for something like `DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM")`...

Comment: I am able to get the month name of today's date by using DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM").But i am not able to retrieve the name of months taken from a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `ToString`, try `string.Format`. Something like:

```
var query = (from e in Employees
           let month = e.BirthDate.GetValueOrDefault()
           let birthmonth = string.Format("{0:MMMM}", month)
           select birthmonth);
query.Dump();
```

This seems to work from my local testing, although it is not included as part of the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in two steps, one to get the months from the database, then another using Linq-To-Objects to perform the formatting.

```
var birthDates = Employees.Select(e => e.BirthDate).ToList();
var query = birthDates.Select(d => d != null ? d.ToString("MMMM") : "Null");
query.Dump();
```

Whatever ORM you are using can't convert the string formatting part of you query into SQL that works on your database. So, doing it in two steps and using `ToList` to evaluate inbetween overcomes that problem.